# TLS1.2 enforced server does not talk to my client

Tags: ssl, certificate

My WebLogic12.1.3 and JAVA1.8 client( SSLV3, TLS1.0. 1.1 and 1.2 enabled) says TLS1.2Hello to a Server which has enforced TLS1.2. But when the message reaches the servers, the server sees SSLV2 hello and rejects the request.

But if I enforced TLS1.2 in my client by setting SSLminimumprotocolversion=TLS1.2, everything works just fine.

Questions:
1) What configurations are needed in my client to talk to TLS1.2 enforced server?
I cant set SSLminimumprotocolversion=TLS1.2 in production since we have other clients talking to us.

2) Can someone please explain this behavior and possible solution?

Regards,
Divya TV

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we found a solution.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SECMG/ssl_version.htm#SECMG637

We set weblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv0 in Weblogic JVM startup.

If the particular minimum protocol you specify is invalid, WebLogic Server enables SSLv3 and all later protocol versions that are supported.And hence doesnt allow SSLV2 hello.